# Create custom control in angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I want to create a custom input to use it in any component
so first step I've created a component like that

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'TextBox',
template: `
<div class="form-group">
<label>{{Caption}}</label>
<input type="text" [required]="IsRequired" class="form-control" [attr.name]="Name" [(ngModel)]="Binding" value="" />
</div>
`,
styleUrls: ['./text-box.component.css']
})
export class TextBoxComponent implements OnInit {
constructor() { }
ngOnInit() {
}
@Input()
public Caption: string;
@Input()
public Name: string;
@Input()
public Binding: any;
@Input()
public IsRequired: boolean;
}
```

than adding this custom input in my HTML like that:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
<TextBox [Caption]="'ClinicName'" 
[Name]="'ClinicName'" 
[Binding]="Model.ClinicName" 
[IsRequired]="true"></TextBox>
<button [disabled]="!form.myForm.valid" class="btn btn-success btn-block ControlButton" (click)="btnSave_click();" id="btnSave">
Save
</button>
</form>
```

all attributes working fine except required
so what I miss here ?

thank you

Comment: How the attribute `isRequired` is not working? Could you please tell more ... ?

Comment: The form became valid even the inner input of TextBox control is empty .. the IsRequired made to make the inner input is required for the form

Comment: there is no form in the TextBox .. just one form in the main component .. I want to make it invalid if the IsRequired is true and inner input of textbox is empty

Answer (score 0):

Replace you your template input code

```
<input type="text" [required]="IsRequired" class="form-control" [attr.name]="Name" [(ngModel)]="Binding" value="" />
```

by  this below:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" 
        [name]="Name" [(ngModel)]="Binding" 
        #name="ngModel" [required]="IsRequired" value="" >
```